# Xamarin forms Map Direction details between two ponits

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin default Map control to show a route between source to destination.By default apple map is loaded in iOS application and google map in android application.  I want to show the direction details(by providing intermediate points ) between the source and the destination.How can I achieve this in Xamarin? Please help me.

Comment: I am sorry but I'm going to have to vote to close. Please read up on the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for posting a question. At the very least you have to show some effort that you have tried yourself. If you did, please let us know in your question before we come up with the same thing. As for your question, have a look at the [TKCustomMap](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/wiki/TKCustomMap) this should have drawing and directions built-in.

Comment: On a side note if you plan on uploading this app to the Google Play store this violates terms of service for Google.

Comment: @yams TOS issue with what?

Comment: Can't publish an app with Turn by turn directions...

Comment: @yams Care to point where? I've been reading the TOS, but couldn't find which TOS and which clause that states this.

Comment: Yes it's in the terms of service.  They prefer you use the native maps app.  Keep reading it's in there.